# Descriptors for moody teenagers?

Tags: word-requests, phrase-request

There are few common ways to describe moody teenagers, albeit not overly precise:

> (很)叛逆(期)

or

> 青春(期)

I'm wondering if there is anything more colorful to describe these cranky kids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

多愁善感 is a common phrase for describing moody

Moody teenagers would be 多愁善感的少年 or simply 多愁少年

林黛玉 in 紅樓夢 is a classic example of 多愁善感的少女 (多愁少女)

~

憤青 short for 憤怒青年 (angry teenager)

~

抑鬱少年 (depress teenager)

~

情緒化 means 'emotional'

情緒化的少年 means 'emotional teenager'